# Connect charger to device first or to power first?

Tags: safety

What reduces the chances of frying a device? Connecting the charger to the power plug first or to the device first?

Comment: Use equipment that doesn't fry stuff - like items not sold on ebay or amazon or aliexpress etc.. Buy from reputable sources equipment that has a data sheet that gives you confidence.

Comment: Let's use "damaging" instead of "frying". If, as mentioned already, this is a concern to you then you're not using decent equipment. In my opinion as a circuit designer it is "trivial" to design a charger that will not damage a device no matter in what order it is connected.

Comment: power first. sometimes the voltage regulation is unstable for a moment or two.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the uncertainty of which way round people will connect them, most devices are built such that it doesn't matter.

However, it's possible that if you sample enough devices and chargers, especially ones not meant for each other, especially cheap no-name or unknown brand ones, then you might find one where it matters.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb,Connecting the charger to the power plug first, then connect the device , so that if something serious up with the power, the charger will blow first....thus saving the device.